# Language syntax for Switch (Javascript and C#) and Select...Case (VBScript) - Combining Cases

Tags: c#, javascript, vbscript

In VB if I wanted to combine a case statment it would look like this

```
Select (somevalue)
  Case 1, 2, 3:
    Do Something
End Select
```

In C# and Javascript

```
switch (someValue) {
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
     //dosomething
     break;
}
```

However this runs without errors in Javascript

```
switch (someValue) {
  case 1, 2, 3:
     break;
}
```

But does not do what is expected.  What is it actually doing?

The reason I ask is because if I hover over the 1, 2, or 3 in firebug it specifies the watch as false.  So clearly the code is evaluating but what is it evaluating.

Comment: `1, 2, 3` is an expression that evaluates to `3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Javascript comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator) evaluates both its operands in left to right order, returning the rightmost. So, you essentially wrote

```
switch (someValue) {
    case 3:
        break;
}
```

Comment: you should expect case 1||2||3 to work, happen to know why it's not?

Comment: @Kooilnc It's not the same thing, with "1 || 2 || 3" the first operand (the 1) evaluates to "true-ish", and so that's what gets returned.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use:

```
switch(true) {
  case (somevalue <= 3): /* action if <= 3 */ break;
  case (somevalue <= 6): /* action if <= 6 */ break;
  //[etc]
  default: 'no action' 
}
```

*Just for fun*: to be able to compare a number against multiple values a Number extension may come in handy:

```
Number.prototype.In = function(){
    var i = -1, args = arguments;
    while (++i<args.length){
         //use float for all numbers
         if (parseFloat(this) === parseFloat(args[i])){
         return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

and then your switch becomes:

```
switch(true) {
  case somevalue.In(1,2,3):   /* action if 1,2,3 */ break;
  case somevalue.In(6,10,14): /* action if 6,10,14 */ break;
  //[etc]
  default: 'no action' 
}
```

See also [O'Reilly - chapter on `switch`](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch06_05.htm)

Comment: Thanks. I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454076/language-syntax-for-switch-javascript-and-c-and-select-case-vbscript-com/4454417#4454417 is a bookmark to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

MDarwi beat me to it, nonetheless he nailed it,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = 5;
switch (x)
{
  case 5, 6, 7:
    document.write("<b>This should work on 5, 6 or 7.</b>");
    break;
  case 0:
    document.write("<b>This should work on 0.</b>");
    break;
}
</script>
```

..writes the first case only when x == 7.